# HTML not displaying tags created from jQuery appropriately

Tags: html, jquery

I have a small jQuery function that is supposed to create dynamic `html` tags filled with data. But only the data is showing without the `html` tags created.

Here's the short `HTML` curled from the original code.

```
<td id="transaction-body">
                        
</td>
```

The `jQuery` is this:

```
function createTable(array) {
     var tableBody = document.getElementById("transaction-body");
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var row = `
          <tr>
            <td align="left" width="55%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">${array[i].name} ${array[i].model}
               </td>
            <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">   ${array[i].qty}
               </td>
            <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;"> ${array[i].price}
               </td>
            <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">
                ${array[i].amount}
               </td>
        </tr>
          `;
          tableBody.innerHTML += row;
     }
}
```

For this, only the data, is being displayed like below;

[image]

Comment: You are inserting a table row into a table cell - change to `<table><tbody id="transaction-body"></tbody></table>`

Comment: Life saver! You're blessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting a table row into a table cell - change to

```
<table><tbody id="transaction-body"></tbody></table>
```

Please try this

```js
const array = [{
    name: "nokia",
    model: "N97",
    qty: 3,
    price: 50,
    amount: 150
  },
  {
    name: "nokia",
    model: "N97",
    qty: 3,
    price: 50,
    amount: 150
  }
];

document.getElementById("transaction-body").innerHTML = array
  .map(({
    name,
    model,
    qty,
    price,
    amount
  }) => `<tr>
      <td>${name} ${model}</td>  
      <td>${qty}</td>
      <td>${price}</td>
      <td>${amount}</td>
      </tr>`)
  .join("")
```

```css
td {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1py solid black;
}

th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: right;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 35%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name/model</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="transaction-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made another update to the table and CSS